# Call specific function from perl module from PowerShell or C#

Tags: c#, perl, powershell

I've a perl script file (.pm) which has many functions like below

```
sub check_row {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
.......
sub find_value {
    my ($class, %args) = @_;
.......
```

Is there any way I can call specific function either via C# or Powershell? I am not allowed to make any change in the .pm file. I am clueless as the tutorial I see on internet talks only about running perl module but not calling any specific function and passing and retrieving value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use Perl modules (`your_module.pm`) directly from PowerShell or C#. You need to run a Perl script (`your_script.pl`) that uses the module:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Your::Module qw(find_value);

find_value ...;
```

or at least pass the code string as a commandline argument to the Perl interpreter, as Mathias R. Jessen pointed out in the comments:

```
perl.exe -w -MYour::Module -e 'find_value ...;'
```

Comment: You could "one-line" the perl call if necessary: `perl.exe -MYour::Module -E 'say find_value(123)'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Granted, but you'll still need a Perl interpreter. PowerShell or C# alone won't suffice.

Comment: Absolutely, he won't get around that in any case

Answer (score 0):

For further research you might have a look at Win32-PowerShell-IPC-0.02.  The documentation states the following:

This module fires up a captive child PowerShell process to which you can submit commands, and receive the results. It's all text for now, but Perl excels at messy stuff like this.